# Android app won't open on Google Play - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, expo, google-play-console

I recently publish my app to the google play, when I installed it on my phone, but the app won't open.I built the app in Expo react native.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be or even how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Try your mobile application in production mode with typing in the terminal at the root of your project

`expo start --no-dev --minify`

It should show your error.

Comment: I run this cmd but there is no error

Comment: Try to open your app in an iPhone simulator if you can, it will show your error